# windows will not allow me to create, copy or move a .licx file

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, licenses.licx

I recently have encountered an issue creating, or moving a .licx file.  It started with a branch from svn and then a checkout.  svn would fail trying to copy in a licx file that my machine created.  In trying to research I realized I can no longer create any file with the .licx extension.  Windows tells me I need permission from myself in order to create it.  I'm the owner of the folder structure all the way up.

Any thoughts or experience with what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Try taking ownership of the folders one by one up the chain, and then try checking in a empty license file. Link on ownership: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html

Comment: @KadeM. I am the owner all the way up the chain.  I actually cannot create a .licx in any folder anywhere on the machine.  Anywhere I try to create even an empty file it tells me I need permission from myself.

Comment: The "need permission from" message is usually just Explorer's way of responding to an access denied error.  Can you create such a file from the command line, e.g., `echo hi > test.licx` or is that blocked too?  If you can do it from the command line but not from Explorer, it might be a problem with a shell extension, if you can't do it from the command line either the most likely cause is security (e.g., anti-virus) software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually do to a bad virus dat blocking this file type. The dat wasn't getting updated due to corruption in the McAfee install (corporate mandated). Once I reinstalled McAfee and updated the dat the problem went away.